# Error executing kriging in modelbuilder: 'invalid output extent'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, error, kriging

I'm doing an interpolation using kriging in Modelbuilder, my model is this:

[image]
Every time I run the model it says:

> ERROR 010092: Invalid output extent. Failed to execute (Kriging).

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The failure of you Kriging model in Modelbuilder is likely a problem with your input feature class. Zoom out to the full extent of your input points to make sure that you do not have any outliers, such as a point at coordinates of 0,0. Next, make sure that your input feature class and your map are in the same projected coordinate system, and that it is correct. Finally, try running your model on a subset of your input points that are bunched fairly closely together.

Comment: My input feature class is from a model with iterate tables, is that a problem? I checked everything you said and it's all ok. Sometimes it gives the error, sometimes not... When it runs correctly it doesn't add the raster to display, why? I have "Add to display" checked.

Comment: I am glad that your model works with some of your input tables. See if you can find out which of your input tables causes your model to fail. Some of them may have missing or transposed coordinates. Can you tell from the geoprocessing window or your model output? If not, you may need to run your data in smaller and smaller batches until you can isolate the bad table. You can also try sorting the coordinate fields in some of the tables to see if there are any values that look out of place.